# Unable to create visual studio 2015 project for mvc 6 in windows10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I want to create a project in visual studio I get:

> DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5' failed to install.  The
>   solution will use DNX SDK version ‘dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5

According to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1039152/DNX-SDK-Version-dnx-clr-win-x-beta-Failed-to) and tgis support [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135) I need to install powershell 3 or 4, but I do have powershell 5 in windows 10.

when I do $PSVersionTable I get:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10240.16384
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   10.0.10240.16384
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
```

When I try to install both powershell 3 and 4 and I'm getting another error:

> The certificate for the signer of the message is invalid or not found

In both cases and I already have installed Windows identity foundation 3.5 in my machine, but it doesn't fix the issue, so I'm stuck on this any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you type 'dnvm list' in console command line?

Answer (score 0):

The article says: Install Windows Powershell 3.0 **(or higher)**

Look at PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 It means that you already have Powershell 3.0.